# How to migrate symfony website from http to https?

Tags: symfony, http, https

I want to migrate my website (which is built using symfony framework) which is currently in http . How can i migrate it  fully to  https version. Do i have to force all http routes to https. How can i change my assets url to https?

Comment: did you hardcoded your URL? if not you don't need to think about it Symfony will manage, just browse as https

Comment: In addition to what @habibun already said, make sure to check external assets. The most flexible way is to use protocol-relative URLs, instead of `http://` or `https://`. More info at: https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Answer (score 0):

you need to change routing,

you need  to add

```
schemes:    [https]
```

in your  yml routing files

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/scheme.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/force_https.html